# Rotating particles of arbitrary spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, group-theory

Is there a way to figure out what is the result of a rotation about an axis of any state in arbitrary spin. Just for example, what is $\hat{R}(\pi/2,\mathbf{y})|2,1\rangle_z$ without their representation in a certain basis. I can make a judgement for spin-1/2 state within 3D frame but what about the other spins?

Comment: So you are asking how to compute something without doing computations?

Comment: I think this is equivalent to asking whether the [Wigner D-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix) is easy to figure out for arbitrary spin, and I think the answer is No, although it was probably easy for Wigner.